# Python program for Armstrong number not outputting correctly

Tags: python

```
 def order(x):
    n=0
    while(x>0):
        n=n+1
        x=x/10
    return n




 def isArmstrong(x):
     n=order(x)
     print(n)
     temp=x
     sum1=0
     while(temp!=0):
         r=temp%10
         sum1=sum1+pow(r,n)
         temp=temp/10

     return (sum1==x)

x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(isArmstrong(x))
```

Comment: Please edit your code.

Comment: first of all it should be        ` x=x//10`

Answer (score 0):

You were not taking integer instead taking some real number to satisfy your condition. So that's the minor mistake you have made.

I made some corrections in

`x/10` --> `x//10`

`temp=temp//10` --> `temp=temp//10`

---

```
 def order(x):
    n=0

    while(x>0):
        n=n+1
        x=x//10 # <-------- Here
    return n




 def isArmstrong(x):
     n=order(x)
     temp=x
     sum1=0
     while(temp!=0):
         r=temp%10
         sum1=sum1+pow(r,n)
         temp=temp//10 # <----------- Here

     return (sum1==x)

x=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(isArmstrong(x))
```

---

Result:

---

```
Enter a number: 100
False
```

---

```
Enter a number: 370
True
```